# Access problem to Hyperlink

Tags: asp.net, hyperlink

I have two nested master page.I add a hyperlink in second master page and I want to change forecolor of hyperlink from a asp page that is connected to it.But,I can't access to hyperlink.

```
HyperLink hpl2 = (HyperLink)Master.FindControl("hplD") as HyperLink;
hpl2.ForeColor = Renk2;
```

After it works upper code,I got the following error.

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Comment: Why you want to change color from server code? Could you describe the scenario?

Comment: It is not causing your error, but you have 2 cast in your first line. Do either `HyperLink hpl2 = (HyperLink)Master.FindControl("hplD")` or `HyperLink hpl2 = Master.FindControl("hplD") as HyperLink;`, but not the two at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

This error may happen either the Master property is null or because the find control didn't found the control so the hpl2 object is null. Can you tell which of them is correct ?!

Comment: Or because the control is not an HyperLink, in which case the `as` operator will return null.

Comment: I think if the control is not HyperLink the error will be invalid cast operation.

Comment: `as` will just return null if the cast is invalid, but I just see that he is casting 2 times.